# Simplifying regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions, kleene-star

I'm having trouble understanding the simplification of the following regular expression

\begin{align}
R = ε | 1 | (ε | 1)(ε | 1)^*(ε | 1) = 1^*
\end{align}

In my lectures only the simplified solution was given but not the steps. I tried on my own but only came this far:

\begin{align}
R & = (ε | 1) | (ε | 1)(ε | 1)^*(ε | 1) \\
& = (ε | 1)[ε | (ε | 1)^*(ε | 1)] \\
& = (ε | 1)(ε | 1)^* \\
& = (ε | 1)^+
\end{align}

I only considered the following Kleene algebra equalities. Let $r$ be a regular expression:

\begin{align}
ε | r(r)^* = r^* = ε | (r)^*r \\
rr^* = r^*r = r^+
\end{align}

What am I missing here?

Comment: try finding out the smallest string the regular expression can generate, and enumerate from there on.

Comment: Almost done. Now you just need to prove that $(\varepsilon|1)^+=1^*$. Try coming back to the definition of $^+$.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself (kinda). As I already guessed, there were some essential laws I was missing.

In addition to regular expression $r$, let $L_1, L_2$ be regular languages:

\begin{align}
(r | ε)^* &= (r)^* \\
(L_1 | ε)(L_2)^* &= (L_2)^*, L_1 \subseteq L_2
\end{align}

Using these, we can continue as follows:

\begin{align}
R & = (ε | 1)(ε | 1)^* \\
& = (ε | 1)(1)^* \\
& = (1)^* \\
& = 1^*
\end{align}

I won't try to claim any credit, a regex simplifier I found online was a great help: http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/regex_simplifier/